# display: inline-block forces new line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

It seems like `display: inline-block` is quite unpopular and People tend to use `float` instead, maybe that is the reason why I could not find a useful answer to my issue.

Given the following snippet, there are 3 boxes. `#b1` has the same height as `#b2` and `#b3` together. Is it somehow possible to display `#b3` directly under `#b2` instead of a new line?

I do not really like `float` because of the `clear:both` I have to append and I am not really sure how to do it with `float` either. Tested it with my knowledge and did not get any better result.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this problem WITHOUT adding a wrapper around `#b2` and `#b3`? Unfortunately the HTML markup cannot be changed.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.block > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.block_50x100 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
}
.block_50x50 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: #00f;
}
.block_50x50+.block_50x50 {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="b1" class="block block_50x100">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b2" class="block block_50x50">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b3" class="block block_50x50">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ofcourse, it will force a new line because you set the width of the first two element to 50%, and there's no available space for the 3rd one.

Comment: No, there isn't since you have eliminated floats. All other current layout methds (excluding CSS grids which has zero support)(and excluding positioning) require an extra wrapper (*unless the height of the container is known*)

Comment: You can still use `float` without `clear`. As your boxes will end up having the same height, the next element will be placed below: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ou70kvor/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, floats are more suitable for this case.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* more reliable way to contain floats
                       by creating the isolated Block Formatting Context (BFC)
                       more on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context */
}
.block {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; /* new BFC again, now to preven overlapping of regular and floating blocks */
}
.block_50x100 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  float: left;
}
.block_50x50 {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: #00f;
}
.block_50x50+.block_50x50 {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="b1" class="block block_50x100">
  </div>
  <div id="b2" class="block block_50x50">
  </div>
  <div id="b3" class="block block_50x50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any inline-* element can't span two or more lines since such elements are laid out by the rules of inline formatting, in the single line while there is enough horizontal space, after which the line wrapping occurs and the new line begins. Only floats can span several lines of text. Another option is to use Flexbox layout with `flex-flow: column wrap`, but this will require to set the explicit height to the container.

Comment: just adding `float:left` to `.block_50x100` worked in my case. is there anything that can go wrong if I do not change the `display` property?

Comment: Also using `flex-flow` is no option because it should stay responsive and therefore the height will not be known. Only option would be using JS but I rather stick with css for the basic layout.

TY for your help and explanation

Comment: @raQai, adding `float` already implicitly changes `display` to `block` (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) and creates new BFC. so in this case it is another working solution.